# What is use of button and hidden controls in HTML and how they work?

Tags: html

```
<button><img src="images" alt="add" width="10" height="10" />Add</button><input type="hidden" name="bookmark" value="lyrics" />
```

I know what the output is but how it is work and where we can use ?

Comment: Button makes a button in a form hidden makes a name/value pair that is submitted with the form but not shown.  This is really very basic html and most tutorials / getting started guides should cover this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know it is unvisible  ,but it can hold some values,   and that is it's effect.
It's a hidden area you submit to the server but do not want the user to notice it .

Comment: Who downvote me ? Why?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but it could be for grammar.